# Save a Copy MXD Error

Tags: arcgis-desktop

How can I fix an MXD that was created with ArcMap 10.5 and then a copy saved as 10.4?

Background: I worked for 2 hours at school creating MXDs I need for a project. After each MXD was saved using ArcMap 10.5, I saved a copy for use with 10.4 at home. I can open the 10.4 copy at home, but none of the layers appear in the TOC. I do not mean that the link to the data is broken which I expect. I mean it shows no layers at all in the data frame or TOC. Only 1 of the MXDs shows the basemap, but the 40 raster files are not there. I do notice the data frame still has the proper projection. Is there a fix or do I have to repeat 2 hours of work?

Comment: In the Tools folder of your ArcGIS install there should be a utility called MXDDoctor.exe, run this and select your MXD and transfer to a new MXD. If this does not fix the document then it's beyond recall and you have to do it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to save a copy of the broken mxd in an even earlier version using python. Execute the code in Idle:

[image]

```
import arcpy

mxdfile=r'C:\TEST\brokenmxd.mxd' #Change path and name to match your MXD

mxd=arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxdfile)
copied_mxd=mxdfile[:-4]+'_10_3.mxd' #The copy will be saved in the same folder as the broken mxd and named ..._10_3.mxd
mxd.saveACopy(copied_mxd,version='10.3')
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP is not asking for another way to Save a Copy, but how to repair an mxd where Save a Copy has not worked.

Comment: Saving a copy of the actual broken mxd like this has worked for me.

Comment: OP is using ArcGIS 10.4 to open an mxd that was saved at 10.5 - your screenshot looks like you're using 10.5 to resave the mxd. The question is, can you repair the mxd using 10.4?

Comment: Code will work with 10.4

Answer (score 0):

MXD doctor did not work. I had another student license code laying around for 10.5, so I uninstalled 10.4 and installed 10.5. The 10.5 MXDs are working now.